# Is importing a module an input or a process?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

This question is really puzzling me, and I cannot work it out. At the start of almost every python program, we `import` things. I am unsure if it is a process, as it is loading something, or if it is an input, as it is inputting the module so that I can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is both; importing a Python module is a process that loads Python code from a file, compiles it (or loads cached bytecode), then executes the bytecode to form a module object with attributes. Loading from a file is input.

And it is neither; a process can also refer to a distinct program managed by the OS, each with its own Process ID, and input could refer to the interaction with the program *after* the modules have been imported, strictly limited to keyboard and mouse input.

You need to be clear what your terminology *means*; define "input" and "process" more clearly and you can figure out the answer from that.

Comment: So, if it is neither, in an example, what would I use in a flow chart/diagram? The square (for a process) or parallelogram (for input) ?

Comment: In a flowchart, I'd represent importing as a process.

Comment: Note that flowcharts are not *that* set in stone; they are communication tool, not a rigid specification.

Comment: Ok. Thanks - So you could use either then, and it would not really matter. Anyway I think I would show it as a process too.

Comment: Accepted as answer - Thanks for the help. :)